# Binding complex model to nested Angular Reactive FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

I have a data object with several layers of arrays and objects, similar to this simplified example. When running this and using the patchValue method as described in the documentation, only the first item in the FooJobHistory FormArray is populated.

How can I bind this FooResume object to the FormGroup?

```
export class FooResume {
    created: Date;
    currentMood: string;
    address: FooAddress;
    jobHistory: FooJobHistory[];
}

export class FooAddress {
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
}

export class FooJobHistory {
    jobHistoryId: number;
    startedDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
    title: string;
    address: FooAddress;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
            created: [''],
            currentMood: ['', [Validators.required]],
            address: this.fb.group({
                address: [''],
                city: ['', [Validators.required]],
                state: ['', [Validators.required]]
            }),
            jobHistory: this.fb.array([
                this.fb.group({
                    jobHistoryId: [''],
                    startDate: [''],
                    endDate: [''],
                    title: [''],
                    address: this.fb.group({
                        address: [''],
                        city: ['', [Validators.required]],
                        state: ['', [Validators.required]]
                    }),
                })
            ])
        });

   this.resumeService.getApplication(this.resumeId).subscribe(x => {
       this.fooResume = x;

       this.form.patchValue(x);
   });
}
```

Comment: well, your whole form should be an array.. Can you set a stackblitz to help you better?

Comment: @Hoch No, it would not be an array because it's not an array. I'm clearly using a made up model to bypass they type of worthless pedantry.